# How to keep bash session open and interactively execute commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am implementing [custom gitlab-runer executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/custom.html#run). Gitlab sends multiple scripts to execute in order, and want to execute them *in the same shell session*. However, my wrapper script is executed multiple times.

While I could do `bash -s <script_from_gitlab.sh` this will execute multiple scripts in a *new* environment. I would want to keep like a "bash service" running with an open input and output, run a command, then when a command is finished collect the output and display it, all while preserving the environment. This is every similar to Jupiter notebooks in python.

How to implement such "persistent bash session" and to execute *one* command in that session and collect it output in non-interactive fashion?

My only idea is to separate output by uuid:

```
#!/bin/bash
prepare() {
   # runs a bash in the background waiting for commands
   mkfifo /tmp/fifoin /tmp/fifoout
   bash -s </tmp/fifoin >/tmp/fifoout &
   echo $! > /tmp/bashpid
}
run() {
   mark=d1c21272-4055-4cd4-a0d4-3462e7d29373
   {
      # executes script
      cat "$1"
      echo "$mark"
   } > /tmp/fifoin &
   while IFS= read -r line; do
       if [[ "$line" == "$mark" ]]; then
            break
       fi
       printf "%s\n" "$line"
   done
}
cleanup() {
   pid=$(</tmp/bashpid)
   kill "$pid"
   tail -f --pid "$pid"
}
# executed with arguments: "cleanup" "run thiscript" "run thatscript" "cleanup" in order
"$1" "$2"
```

However, this feels like a workaround, especially with the "mark" to get if the script finished execution or not. Is there a different solution?

In real life, the commands are run by Nomad scheduler. It's the same, just `bash -s` is executed with `nomad exec <allocid> bash -s`.

Comment: use GNU screen or tmux? or my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can interact with the bash session in a programmable way.

Comment: How would I grab the command output to stdout? Also, I do not want the commands to see a terminal. I do not think this is related.

Comment: with GNU screen or tmux, you can redirect all the output to some file which you can read later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attempt, hope it can be adapted to meet your requirements :

```
#!/bin/sh

input=/tmp/pipe-input
output=/tmp/pipe-output

# Wait for commands from $input and send results to $output
server(){
    rm -f $input $output
    mkfifo $input $output
    while true; do
        echo "Hello from server." >&2
        eval "$(cat $input)" > $output
    done
}

client(){ 
    cat > $input; cat $output
}

# Send commands to server every second.
test-client(){
    for i in {1..6}; do
        client <<< 'echo $(date +%T) server hostname=$(hostname), server bash PID=$$'
        sleep 1
    done
    client <<< 'exit'
}

"$@"
```

In one window, run

```
bash test.sh server
```

In another window, run

```
bash test.sh test-client
```

I think the usage of `eval` is "tolerable" as you are in control of the commands to run.